# iOS dynamically moved images won't stay put

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am writing an app for iPhone, which upon loading, moves a few UIImages to specific places on the screen. When the app first comes up, everything is where I want it. But if I show a modal page, as that page is transitioning in, the images "pop back" to their old places for a split second while the page comes up. (Even if I call the image moving code again in the same event). Then when I dismiss the modal page, the images won't move at all, even though it does show my image mover event runs in the log.
Here is my code:

```
-(void)ajustScreen
{
NSLog(@"Move Images");
self.imageA.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);
self.imageB.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);
self.imageA.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
self.imageB.center = CGPointMake(180, 180);
}
```

I have this code here:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(ajustScreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

fired off when the screen rotates, in viewWillAppear, viewWillDisappear, viewDidLoad, and then in an NSNotificationCenter that is supposed to call it when a modal is dismissed.

```
-(void)sendToAbout
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ajustScreen) name:@"SecondViewControllerDismissed" object:nil];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"goabout" sender: self];
}
```

(And in the modal):

```
- (IBAction)BackButton:(id)sender {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SecondViewControllerDismissed"
                                                    object:nil
                                                  userInfo:nil];
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

What confuses me is that there are no errors, and each time, the log prints out that it was run, but it doesn't consistently work.

Comment: Have you tried running your code inside of `layoutSubviews`?

Comment: Never heard of them. How would I do that?

Comment: Moreover, I would like to point out that you must not set frame in background thread, It has to be on main thread. layoutSubviews will be overridden in subclass of UIView. Why are calling adjustScreen on viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewWillDisappear, call the method in viewWillAppear only?

Comment: @Idindu As of iOS 7, viewWillAppear is not triggered prior to a modal being dismissed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `UIViewController` method `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.imageA.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);
    self.imageB.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);
    self.imageA.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
    self.imageB.center = CGPointMake(180, 180);
}
```

*On a side note:* 
Rather than using Notification Center to notify the closing of the modal and allowing the modal to dismiss itself, it's better practice to create a protocol for the modal. Then set your view controller as the delegate and dismiss the modal controller from a delegate method.

It certainly will work the way you have it, but it forces you to use the notification center. Plus, if you use the completion block, you don't run the risk of having your object removed from memory before the block completes it's process.

Comment: Works brilliantly, thanks a lot!
That is a good suggestion, I will change that in my original code.